# How to restore Outlook to Exchange access after cable to DSL switch?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, exchange, outlook

We have an Active Directory domain, using Exchange 2003 for email. Our incoming mail suddenly dropped, and after much troubleshooting, we determined that it was caused by our Comcast cable modem. Switching our connection to our Verizon DSL modem fixed the problem. We had to change our DNS record with GoDaddy to point to the right address, but once that took effect, our internal email worked.

Problem is, our remote users out in the field (who use the Outlook Web Access client) and some users in our remote offices (using standard Outlook client) still are not able to get email. What else do we need to change to get them access? I believe it should be something simple like forwarding port 443 on our firewall, but I don't know the details. (Our main IT guy is on vacation, so I'm trying to scramble and figure this out myself.) Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as OWA is concerned, you're right on the money. You need to set up your DSL modem to forward port 443 (and possibly port 80 depending on your Exchange configuration) to your Exchange server.

If the remote office users are running Outlook in RPC over HTTP/HTTPS mode, then the above should get them working as well.